# shared library text segment is not shareable

Tags: android, shared-libraries, ld

I am trying to add HW video acceleration to a cm10.2 port for my device. I get no errors but the one below, then `make` stops working, apparently without any error.

```
/home/vektor/CM102/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable
/home/vektor/CM102/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: treating warnings as errors
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/vektor/CM102/out/target/product/s7300b/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libamplayer_intermediates/LINKED/libamplayer.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

What does it mean? Should I compile with less restrictive flags or is something worse causing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Update:***

from Android NDK r11 you can use

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel
```

You can also use

```
LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS := true
```

***Previous answer:***

This is a recent change in toolchain which treats this warning as an error.

One workaround is to add `--no-warn-shared-textrel` to `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` to disable treating warning as an error. You can do that in your `Android.mk` like

```
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := --no-warn-shared-textrel
```

Comment: Adding this `LOCAL_DISABLE_FATAL_LINKER_WARNINGS := true` to Android.mk works better, than `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` solution.

Comment: Since r11, The `build/core/build-binary.mk` will always add the `LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel` at the end of the link command no matter what `LOCAL_LDFLAGS` I have set before. How to avoid this?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: What does it mean?

Answer (score 4):

Workaround for Android NDK r11:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel
```

`LOCAL_LDLIBS` is applied later in the option chain than `LOCAL_LDFLAGS`, and consequently overrides the default.

Comment: This does provide an answer, which works better than the accepted answer for newer version of Android NDK.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

For asop project(eg: aosp/external/myproject/)

add this line to your android.mk

`LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -w -frtti`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to set

```
APP_LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel
```

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk#app_ldflags