# AndrABEn : compilation error when running ndk-build

Tags: android-ndk, gmp

i am trying to compile the library AndrABEn for android, but i get the following error when i run ndk-build [error ndk-build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgjpL.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shared library text segment is not shareable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986523/shared-library-text-segment-is-not-shareable)

Comment: i've already seen that, doesn't resolve anything