# warning: shared library text segment is not shareable

Tags: android, c++, ffmpeg, android-ndk, cmake

I explain my problem :

My project is an android application using C++ with NDK.

I have to include the library ffmpeg into my project.

I've built ffmpeg with this tuto : https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android (I've looked at the script, it looks like it's built for a static link)

My cmakelist.txt is working, no error. But when i run my program, i got this message :
(i've cut it or it's too long)

> [1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libgestionnaire.so
>
> /local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: warning: shared library text segment is not shareable
>
> /local/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: error: treating warnings

Best Regards

Comment: The title is meaningless. You get warning `shared library text segment is not shareable`, which (according to the linker options) is treated as error. When google for warning message the first reference gives [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986523/shared-library-text-segment-is-not-shareable). Its answers suggest to use linker option `-Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel` for suppress such warnings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I was not sure about the title (i'm a true beginner). So in my cmakelist i added this : set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS `"${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11 -Wl --no-warn-shared-textrel")`

And now i got this message error (the good part i guess) :
 `clang++: error: unsupported option '--no-warn-shared-textrel'`

Comment: This is a **linker** option, so you should assign variable *CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS*. Also, **comma** after `-Wl` is a **part of the option**, and no space should be after it.

Comment: You're right, the problem came from the coma. But i still have the same issue with those flags

Comment: Oops, I just found that CMake has different variables for different types of objects. For shared libraries this is [CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS.html) variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I update with the solution

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. It's perfectly okay to accept your own answer (and having an accepted answer makes it easier for others to find it).

Comment: Thais for the advice, i'll do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, so thanks to @textrel and @Tsyvarev, i could resolve my problem, it was pretty easy :

I just added those lines in my cmakelist.txt :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wall -v -Wl,--no-warn-shared-textrel")
```

Best regards

Comment: --no-warn-shared-textrel cause "has text relocations" error on runtime